Problem with "next build" on creating a react app: Export encountered errors on following paths:
I tried to initiate a react app on my Windows but i just can't do it.
On the project directory I ran next build, but the following error was shown:
  Export encountered errors on following paths:

        /_error: /404
        /_error: /500
        /_not-found/page: /_not-found
        /page: /

it seems that the project directory should have a directory called "pages" with several docs to defined the routes, but none of them exist.
Do I have to create each one of them, or something else?
This is the project directory structure (according to gpt chat):
pages/
├── index.js
├── about.js
├── posts/
│   ├── [slug].js
│   └── index.js

I tried to reinstall npm, next and react. But the same error appeared.

Please provide a clear directory structure of your app (specially pages directory). I guess your error has something to do with these pages not being implemented correctly.
